# PHP Require - response on failure

Tags: php, require

I'm using ajax call to send a message from my contact form. However, I want to print the server response back to user, if it succeeds or if it fails, and I want to report if class.phpmailer.php is missing for some reason, but this isn't working for me, so how could I display a custom error message on require failure?

```
require "class.phpmailer.php"; or die("<span style='color:red;'>Tiedosto class.phpmailer.php puuttuu! Viestin lähetys epäonnistui!</span>");
```

Comment: Use `if(file_exists('class.phpmailer.php')){ include "class.phpmailer.php"; }else{ echo"does not exist"; }` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check that the files exists first then do an import, if the file cannot be found then it will display your message back to the user.

```
if(file_exists('class.phpmailer.php')){ 
    include "class.phpmailer.php"; 
}else{ 
    echo"<span style='color:red;'>Tiedosto class.phpmailer.php puuttuu! Viestin lähetys epäonnistui!</span>"; 
}
```

Comment: if a required file is not present in a php script, is not the user who should be alerted, is the script owner. As a security policy is better for scripts to fail fast then hide the errors and continue with unexpected results

Comment: Probably but thats not what the question asked ;P

Answer (score 0):

Require produces an E_COMPILE_ERROR which is not catchable in your IF.

Comment: `if(file_exists('class.phpmailer.php')){ include "class.phpmailer.php"; }else{ echo"does not exist"; }` seems to be working.

Comment: it was a require not include, include will only throw an warning. So it works but then you lose the main idea of using a require instead of an include, which is to have the error alert

Comment: when you use the require is because you want it to stop, to prevent other damage that the script can do without the proper included file

Comment: The purpose is for you to understand WHY it works not just to work :)